# I want a function that converts one dict to another dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I need a python function that converts from one dict to another. here is some example of input dict and expected output dict.
for 'pc' the internal values are not there so make it as empty value, for camera may be all the key of internal not present. need to check. if not present need to put the key and make the value as empty

input1

```
[
    {
        'calculation': {
            'model': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal': {
                'type': '',
                'length': [],
                'point': [],
                'cau': '',
                'cal': ''
            }
        },
        'name': 'pc'
    },
    {
        'calculation': {
            'model': {
                'model': 't'
            },
            'internal': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        0,
                        -0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        -0.9240056599999997,
                        -2.0340000799999998,
                        -0.8554816599999998,
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            'name': 'camera'
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'straight',
        'length': [
            458.37,
            458.37
        ],
        'point': [
            768.0,
            499.39
        ],
        'cau': -20.0,
        'cal': 20.0
    }
]
```

input2

```
[
    {
        'calculation': {
            'model': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal': {
                'type': '',
                'length': [],
                'point': [],
                'cau': '',
                'cal': ''
            }
        },
        'name': 'pc'
    },
    {
        'calculation': {
            'model': {
                'model': 'f'
            },
            'internal': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        -2.12607049,
                        -0.0056704,
                        -1.45264044,
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            'name': 'camera'
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'normal',
        'length': [
            2492.37,
            2492.37
        ],
        'point': [
            3045.0,
            2166.581065
        ]
    }
]
```

output1

```
[
    {
        'name': 'pc',
        'calculation': {
            'model': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal': {
                'type': '',
                'length': [],
                'point': [],
                'cau': '',
                'cal': ''
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'camera',
        'calculation': {
            'model': 't',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        0,
                        -0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0.9999999999999998,
                        0,
                        -0.9240056599999997,
                        -2.0340000799999998,
                        -0.8554816599999998,
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal': {
                'type': 'straight',
                'length': [
                    458.37,
                    458.37
                ],
                'point': [
                    768.0,
                    499.39
                ],
                'cau': -20.0,
                'cal': 20.0
            }
        }
    }
]
```

output2

```
[
    {
        'name': 'pc',
        'calculation': {
            'model': '',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal': {
                'type': '',
                'length': [],
                'point': [],
                'cau': '',
                'cal': ''
            }
        }
    },
    {
        'name': 'camera',
        'calculation': {
            'model': 'f',
            'external': {
                'from': {
                    'elements': [
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        -2.12607049,
                        -0.0056704,
                        -1.45264044,
                        1
                    ]
                }
            },
            'internal':{
                'type': 'normal',
                'length': [
                    2492.37,
                    2492.37
                ],
                'point': [
                    3045.0,
                    2166.581065
                ],
                'cau': '',
                'cal': ''
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I have tried so far as:

```
def convert_dict(input_dict):
    output_dict = []

    for item in input_dict:
        name = item.get('name', '')
        calculation = item.get('calculation', {})
        model = calculation.get('model', '')
        external = calculation.get('external', {})
        internal = calculation.get('internal', {})

        # Check if 'internal' key is present and not empty
        if internal:
            # Check if 'type', 'length', 'point', 'cau', and 'cal' keys are present
            if 'type' not in internal:
                internal['type'] = ''
            if 'length' not in internal:
                internal['length'] = []
            if 'point' not in internal:
                internal['point'] = []
            if 'cau' not in internal:
                internal['cau'] = ''
            if 'cal' not in internal:
                internal['cal'] = ''

        # Check if 'external' key is present and not empty
        if external:
            # Check if 'from' key is present and not empty
            if 'from' in external and 'elements' not in external['from']:
                external['from']['elements'] = []

        # Build the output dictionary
        output_item = {
            'name': name,
            'calculation': {
                'model': model,
                'external': external,
                'internal': internal
            }
        }

        output_dict.append(output_item)

    return output_dict

output_data = convert_dict(input_data)
print(output_data)
```

but internal part is missing in the output.

Comment: It's not ALWAYS working... It's not working when internal is a string in the input because when you use `internal = calculation.get('internal', {})` it is returning a string because the key exists. `dict.get` only returns the default value when the key doesn't exist. and all your checks only check to see if a string exist in that string. Maybe check if `internal` is a dict before continuing to build the dict.

Answer (score 0):

I explained in my comment why it's not working. Basically when `internal` exists in the dict at all `calculations.get` returns the value which in some cases is an empty string and others it's a dict. In the case it's a string your checks are going to fail on an empty string every time.

You could try replacing `internal`'s assignment with this:

```
internal = calculation.get('internal') or {}
```

Which will return a empty dict even if `internal` is an empty string.

(P.S) this won't work if internal is a truthy string though. You would need a check to see if `internal` is a dict or not if any of your data were to have something undesired in there.

If that's the case you could try this:

```
internal = calculation.get('internal')
if not isinstance(internal, dict):
    internal = {}
```